# HTML multiple tables placement

Tags: html, html-table

I have 3 separate HTML tables.
I need to place 2 of them side by side, and the 3rd table below the right side table.
my current HTML tables placement:

[table1]  [table2]
(empty)   [table3]

But right now the problem I am facing is the table 2 and table 3 are too close to each together, I need to have a gap between the table 2 and table 3
which should look like this:

[table1]  [table2]

(empty)   [table3]

I've tried a lot of ways already, any help would be deeply appreciated!
*Please note that the tables are 3 SEPARATED tables.

*Unable to upload the images of my current table, lack of rep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this you can also use table inside table but that is bad idea.

```
<div id="main">
      <div id="left" style="float:left;">table1<div>
      <div id="right" style="float:left;">table2<div>
      <div id="bottom" style="float:right;width:sameastable2div;padding-top:2px;">table3<div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use table attribute cellspacing for the main table you are using so as to give space among the table cells.

```
  <table border="1" cellspacing="5">
    <tr><td><table></table></td><td><table></table></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td><table></table></td></tr>
  </table>
```